# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. on CenOS 6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, redmine, gem-bundler

Installing Redmine.
I've tried,

```
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite
```

, but error.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161228-21055-1dxe9y9.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
generator.c:861: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this
function)
generator.c:861: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only
once
generator.c:861: error: for each function it appears in.)
generator.c:863: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this
function)
At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign"
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option
"-Wno-constant-logical-operand"
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option
"-Wno-parentheses-equality"
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option
"-Wno-tautological-compare"
make: *** [generator.o] error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

So, I've tried `gem install json -v '1.8.3`, but I couldn't solve it.

Would you mind just read this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby 2.4 is very new. In fact, it was released only 3 days ago.

Since there are several impirtant internal changes in Ruby 2.4, it is quite likely that many gems (and Redmine itself) are not yet compatible with this version of Ruby.

From your error message, it does indeed seem that the JSON gem needs to be adapted in order to handle some changes in Ruby 2.4 regarding whole numbers.

You should use an older version of Ruby for now, e.g. Ruby 2.3.3. As you can see on http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Ruby-interpreter, Redmine requires specific Ruby versions depending on the version of Redmine.

Comment: I see... That means Ruby 2.4 do not support JSON 1.8.3. Then, is there any information that stable(?) gems list following ruby version?
I wanna know searching keyword to do myself.

Comment: Well, each gem implements their own compatibility mechanisms. To be sure, you have to read the documentation, try it or ask the maintainers. You can also google for "[gemname] ruby 2.4" or "[gemname] [error message]". As for the json gem, they support Ruby 2.4 [since json 2.0](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/CHANGES.md#2015-09-11-200). The required changes [were backported to the 1.8 branch](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/308) but are not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right now.
To solve it install the latest version of `bundler` and `rmagick` manually using `gem install` update all other packages with `gem update` and `bundle update`.
This solved this dependency issue of `json 1.8.3` and `ruby 2.4`.

But I run in some more problems afterwords.
It seams like `ruby 2.4` does some changes in the interpretation of number which means it is not compatible with `rail 4.x` anymore [(see this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-0-8-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror).
Updating `rails` and its dependencies seems to be not possibles yet as redmine needs `protected_attributes` which depends on
      `activemodel (< 5.0, >= 4.0.1)` and `rails 5.x` depends on
      `activemodel 5.x`.

It is always bad if an update breaks backward compatibility especially for programming language :(

Answer (score -1):

first run

```
gem install bundler
```

It installs the newer bundler and solves the native extension dependencies

then run

```
bundle install
```

it should solve the your issue

Answer (score -1):

it seems that the json gem is having a bug with newer ruby version (2.4+), that [answer](https://makandracards.com/makandra/74544-how-to-fix-json-1-8-3-with-ruby-2-5) from makandracards is proposing a simple and easy solution.

the answer is about updating the version of json gem to tackle the bug and successfully install the gem. so, it updates the json gem with --conservative option.

`bundle update json --conservative`