# stack level too deep (SystemStackError) RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote `rails s` and got this:

```
 jonsdirewolf@DESKTOP-GNM7V6T:/mnt/c/Users/direwolf/Documents/web/rails_projects/myapp$ rails s
    /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions in PATH, mode 040777
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
    /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
    Exiting
    /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
             ... 5012 levels...
            from /home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /mnt/c/Users/direwolf/Documents/web/rails_projects/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
            from bin/rails:3:in `load'
            from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    jonsdirewolf@DESKTOP-GNM7V6T:/mnt/c/Users/direwolf/Documents/web/rails_projects/myapp$
```

What do I do?

Comment: It's a bug. Please follow monkey patch given in the ticket comment or upgrade rails to 4.2.8
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25125

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal I get an errror from patch

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal jonsdirewolf@DESKTOP-GNM7V6T:/mnt/c/Users/direwolf/Documents/web/rails_projects/test_app$ `cp -r ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/ac
tivesupport-4.2.7.1 vendor/gems
cp: cannot stat '/home/jonsdirewolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1': No such file or directory`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.4 and Rails 4.0.8 stack level too deep (SystemStackError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-0-8-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror)