# <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

```
[pcms (master)]$ rails generate rollbar
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:90: warning: already 
initialized constant FileUtils::VERSION
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:92: 
warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1188: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::S_IF_DOOR
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1267: warning: previous definition of S_IF_DOOR was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1446: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::DIRECTORY_TERM
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1541: warning: previous definition of DIRECTORY_TERM was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1448: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::SYSCASE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1543: warning: previous definition of SYSCASE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1501: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1596: warning: previous definition of OPT_TABLE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1555: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LOW_METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1650: warning: previous definition of LOW_METHODS was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1562: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1657: warning: previous definition of METHODS was here
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.4, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
5368: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
5367: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
5366: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
5365: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
5364: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
5363: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
5362: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
5361: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
 ... 5356 levels...
   4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
   3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
   2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
   1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Not sure how to fix this. I'm trying to Install Rollbar for our Heroku Platform Application.

Nokogiri Gem is installed

I'm not the original editor for this app. Just trying to fix everything.

Rails 4.2.1

Gemfile
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.10'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.7.1'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4.1'


# heroku installed add-ons
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'raygun4ruby'

# nokogiri 1.6.2 segmentation faults when running rspec
gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.1'
gem 'rspec'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0'
gem 'highcharts-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.16.3'
gem 'simple_calendar', '~> 1.1.10'
gem 'rqrcode', '0.4.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.2.13'
gem 'pg_search', '~> 0.7.9'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '~> 1.4.0'
gem "sentry-raven", git: "https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby.git"

# optimization and cleanup
gem 'traceroute'
gem 'pry-byebug', '~> 3.4'
gem 'cancan'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.6.0'
gem 'rack-timeout' # used to timeout puma requests

group :production do
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem "bugsnag", "~> 6.7"
```

Doesn't matter what I try to install, I get a result with stack level too deep (SystemStackError). The original files are not mind, I just took over after that person left.

I can't even update the app remotely without an issue.

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec rails generate rollbar`?

Comment: yes. stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.4 and Rails 4 stack level too deep (SystemStackError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror). That should help

Comment: I read the duplicate trend but didn't help.

Comment: Rails 4.2.1 is running

Comment: Yes you need to get up over rails 4.2.8 or drop your ruby version to < 2.4

Comment: upgrade rails to 4.2.8  ... still having the issue. should i go higher than 4.2.8?