# Ruby Upgrade Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I upgraded my ruby gem and rails to the latest version. Fixed all the dependencies but still, I am unable to start my rails application. 
When I try rails s, I get the below error. I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5437: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    5436: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    5435: from /Users/sri/Documents/imcmarketplace/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    5434: from /Users/sri/Documents/imcmarketplace/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    5433: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    5432: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    5431: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    5430: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     ... 5425 levels...
       4: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       3: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       2: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       1: from /Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/Users/sri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Thanks
Sri

Comment: what is your ruby version?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to your `ruby` and `rails` version and I think you need to downgrade ruby version or upgrade the rails version

for more check here [Ruby 2.4 and Rails 4 stack level too deep (SystemStackError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue goto `Gemfile` use `gem 'spring'` don't add the version of the spring. Then do the `bundle install`. Still, you have an issue remove the `Gemfile.lock` then do the `bundle install`. I hope this will help you.