# Ruby on rails heroku crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was a little ways into a rails app I was putting together, and I decided I would try and deploy to heroku. After finally getting it pushed up, it began crashing. I received an H10 Error. Whenever I tried running Heroku console to debug, I got an error, so I thought, maybe I'll just create a new rails app, deploy it right at the get go, and copy past most of my old code over so I can figure out at what point it breaks. So I did that, and I've done nothing to the app and it crashes from the get go. Locally it's fine, but I still can't access the live version of the site OR access heroku console. PLEASE ADVICE

Some code:

```
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141272+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141273+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141274+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141276+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141277+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141279+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141286+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141280+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141290+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141295+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141288+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141293+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141301+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141294+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141297+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141303+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141298+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141300+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141304+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141306+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141307+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141309+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141310+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141312+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141313+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141315+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141316+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141291+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141319+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141317+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141320+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141330+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141329+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141333+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141334+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141336+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141337+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141323+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141322+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141339+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141340+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141332+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141342+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141355+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141358+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141348+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141351+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141349+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141359+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141343+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141345+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141361+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141367+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141364+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141362+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141357+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141374+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141365+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141346+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141368+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141375+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141378+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141377+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141380+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141384+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141385+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141382+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141386+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141381+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141400+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141395+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141401+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141398+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141397+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141388+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141389+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141391+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141392+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141394+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141421+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141423+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141425+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141426+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141428+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141430+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141418+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141408+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141433+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141431+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141434+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141403+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141410+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141415+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141416+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141404+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141420+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141405+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T20:46:53.141407+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
2018-06-20T21:35:17.966077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=warm-tor-22831.herokuapp.com request_id=62398895-5f73-4a4c-9e81-f16615258891 fwd="73.211.82.19" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-20T21:35:18.178131+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-tor-22831.herokuapp.com request_id=41510aaf-8ca1-44f5-81c6-1a9a5f860abc fwd="73.211.82.19" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's the Error I receive when I attempt to open heroku console:

```
Running console on ⬢ warm-tor-22831... up, run.4740 (Free)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
     ... 8072 levels...
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Hooo boy am I kinda frustrated. Crossing my fingers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way I'm using puma because I was advised to do so.

Comment: did you upgrade your ruby and rails version?, because in ruby 2.4 `Fixnum` and `Bignum` are the same thing as `Integer` check here https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby 2.4, there was a unification of integer types (i.e. Fixnum and Bignum are now the very same thing: Integer). This results on quite a few incompatibilities with existing gems which relied on the distinction of the classes.

Older versions of ActiveSupport are among those which don't like this unification and barf over it when trying to serialize data. As such, you have one of two options:

You can downgrade Ruby to a version earlier than 2.4, e.g. Ruby 2.3.x.
Or you could upgrade Rails to a newer version. Preferably, that could be Rails 5.x. There is also a patch in the 4.2-stable branch which was released with Rails 4.2.8, making it the first version of the Rails 4.2 series that officially supports Ruby 2.4. Earlier Rails versions are not compatible with Ruby 2.4.

Comment: Ayyyy, thanks! I kept seeing fixnum and was like, that... looks like an issue! I'll probably just go ahead and bump up to 5 then. +1 to the dude below me too, but I'm not even ALLOWED TO VOTE YET. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in ruby 2.4 in which Fixnum and Bignum are combined to Integer.

Now, the ActiveSupport older versions seems incompatible over the above two classes when serializing data.

So either you can downgrade to a lower ruby version or Upgrade to a new Rails version(ie new ActiveSupport Version).

Also there is a corresponding SO link for the same:

[Ruby 2.4 and Rails 4 stack level too deep (SystemStackError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror)