# Error when migrating Rails App in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I have an application in rails 4.2.7.1, when I run the db:migrate in test in works perfectly

```
➜ bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test

➜ bundle exec rake db:ceate RAILS_ENV=test

➜ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

But when I ran it in development, only the last migration or beginning from a drop database after executing firs migration I get this:

```
➜ bundle exec rake db:migrate -- --trace
== 20191112204156 MyNewModel: migrating ==============================
-- create_table(:global_clients)
   -> 0.0121s
== 20191112204156 MyNewModel: migrated (0.0122s) =====================

rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using ruby 2.1.6, and mysql 0.318 and later 0.4.10, I did rvm implode to start it again and nothing happens. I do not know how to solve it, even I do not know how to debug it. So any tips will be good.

It's a problem with dthe difference from rais test and development environments

Comment: Try to upgrade to Rails 4.2.8 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41504382/9269043

Comment: About debugging - try to find the same issue in gems which you are using ONLY in dev env

Comment: @Vasilisa, thanks for this tip, you where absolutely right, I added the development gems to group test gems, and failed in test environment, then updating I found the problem with bullet gem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.4 and Rails 4 stack level too deep (SystemStackError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror)