# I have an old Rails app that won't load in Mac Terminal anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal

I have a Rails app that I made four years ago. I'm trying to load it now in Terminal on Mac and it won't load. When I type `rails console` I get the following:

`` Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated. Please use a String or nil. An Array ({"GEM_PATH"=>["/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0", "/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global"]}) was passed in from bin/rails:3:in `load' /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated ``

then some other stuff, and then the last line:

`` from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>' from /Users/[username]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' from /Users/[username]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' from -e:1:in `<main>' ``

What do I need to do here?

[Update - a commenter asked me to post the whole error message so here's what it was:]

````
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in `is_a?': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
     ... 5523 levels...
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/[username]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'```
````

Comment: The first part you show are some warnings, that shouldn't cause it to fail. The second part you show is the end of a stacktrace, but you omitted the rest where it should tell you the error.

Comment: I edited my question to include the whole error text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror